# PowerShell - Stringing Array Values together

Tags: powershell

I'm quite new to PowerShell and have been running into a problem while trying to program a script that calculates the value of an electric resistor based on it's colour code. My problem is that while the script already is able to choose the number of rings the resistor has and select the appropriate values for them, I just can't manage to "glue" the values for the first two or three (depending on type) rings together into another variable.
To make this clear, the first two/three rings are not supposed to be summarized or anything like that, but the digits have to be "written behind each other".

All variables used (except $ring*n*a, which are hashtables) are initialized as Integer - which to my belief is why I'm not able to put those numbers together.

The code I hoped would be able to complete the task looks like the following at the moment:

```
$val_res = 0
$val_z = 0
$ring1val = $ring1a.Get_Item($ring1e)
$ring2val = $ring2a.Get_Item($ring2e)
$ring3val = $ring3a.Get_Item($ring3e)
$ring4val = $ring4a.Get_Item($ring4e)

$val_z = ($ring1val $ring2val $ring3val)
$val_res = ($val_z * $ring4v)
```

I know that the code in $val_z produces an error at the moment - and I already tried using "-and" to glue those numbers together in $val_z, but to no avail; it then just returned "true" as it's value.

Sorry if this question might already has been answered before, but I couldn't find anything similar. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two or three rings represent decimal digits. You have to multiply each digit by its corresponding power of ten.  You can then apply the multiplier.  For four-band resistors, the formula is:

```
resistance = (ring1 * 10 + ring2) * 10 ^ ring3
```

For five-band resistors, the formula is

```
resistance = (ring1 * 100 + ring2 * 10 + ring3) * 10 ^ ring4
```

http://www.digikey.com/us/en/mkt/calculators/4-band-resistors.html
http://www.digikey.com/us/en/mkt/calculators/5-band-resistors.html

Comment: Hey Robert, thanks a lot. Tried it and works perfectly. I guess sometimes I'm just to blind to see things like these. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays can be constructed in powershell using commas: (2,3,4)